# Twitter widget in Ionic 4 app on iOS device

Tags: ionic-framework, twitter, ionic4

I'm developing an Ionic 4 application for web/android/ios, in which I show some dynamic text on some pages, that also includes tweets.

However, I have encountered a problem in a compiled iOS application, where tweets aren't displayed.

Basically, I load twitter script in app.component.ts in a function

```
  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js: any,
            fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            p='https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
        return true;
    }
    (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
  }
```

Then I load the text from a backend and insert the following code into page:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
<p lang="en" dir="ltr">[contents]</p>&mdash; Name (@[Handle]) 
<a href="https://twitter.com/[Handle]/status/1125039697040957441?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">May 5, 2019</a>
</blockquote>
```

And when I need to render all tweets, I call `twttr.widgets.load();`, which is available and works. It converts the code before into a well-rendered embedded widget.

Results:

**Web application:** works

**Android application:** works

**Web app in mobile Safari:** works

**iOS application:** does not work

Example of working result (web/android): 
[image: working on web and android, example result]

As you can see, tag is populated here. Renders fine.

On the other hand, the result on iOS is this:
[image: does not work on iOS, example result]

Take note that the blockquote tag is not deleted, and `<twitter-widget>` tag is not populated.

I have tested on a remote debugging, and I have found that the widget does all needed queries to the twitter servers, and I even see in a Network tab that it returns a correct response. However, `<twitter-widget>` tag is never populated, and I cannot force it to display any kind of error.

This is exclusive to compiled iOS application only.

What to do? `twttr.widgets.createTweet()` doesn't work either with the same results.

Expected result: Twitter embeds should load everywhere.

Actual result: Twitter embeds load everywhere, except compiled iOS application.